# Cufon doesn't work inside javascript

Tags: javascript, cufon

I have the following problem.
I have some text within a javascript. I want the text to look nice, so I wrapped it with "h3" which carries a cufon canvas javascript modifier, so it will look different from the normal font.
However, text within Javascript doesn't seem to be affected by cufon.

I've tried a few things to make it work, but nothing seems to work.

This is the code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var author = $('#author').val();
  if( author !='' && $('#email').val() !='' ) {
    $('#authorData').hide();
    $('#authorData').before('<div id="welcome"> <h3>Welcome back, <strong>' + author + '</strong>! <a href="#">Edit &raquo;</a></h3></div>')
    $('#welcome a').toggle(
      function() {
        $('#authorData').show(300);
        $(this).html('Minimize &raquo;');
        return false;
      },
      function() {
        $('#authorData').hide(300);
        $(this).html('Edit &raquo;');
        return false;
      }
    );
  }

});
```

My idea is to get the whole "weclome div" into the actual php and out of the javascript code and just leave a "redirector" in the javascript, but I'm not sure if that's possible at all.

Any ideas how to make this work?

My cufon script looks like this:

```
 Cufon.replace('h1',{hover: true})('h2')('h3')('.stepcarousel .panel .caption .title');
```

P.S.: It kind of works in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. Very weird!

Thanks a lot for any advice and suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cufon doesn't work if element or parent is display: none ( you are using hide() ). Use visibility hidden instead.

Comment: Hello. I see. I tried to exchange the hide() by visibility:hidden() but it doesn't work. I'm not very familiar with jQuery, could you help me and show me how the code should look instead? Thank you :)

Comment: Hello again. I tried to google it, but I just cannot get it to work. Do I have to use  `$("div:hidden").show();` instead for the hide(); or something completely else??!! Please help. :)

Comment: Thank you. So what you're saying is that I should try to paste a "Cufon.replace" snippet into the js code I posted in my question?

Comment: Yes or try in that place refresh like James suggested

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be appending the content after the DOM is ready. You haven't shown in your code where you actually call the `Cufon.now()` method, but I'm assuming it's called before your elements are appended to the DOM.

If you check the [Cufon API](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API) you will see the `refresh` method, which can be called to do precisely that:

`Cufon.refresh();`

You need to call the `refresh` method if new text is added to the document, or even if existing text changes (e.g. font size is increased).

Comment: Hello. I'm not really familiar with Cufon. It was already in my parent theme like that. Need to figure out how to do that I guess. Is that directly in the js file?